# Why does sed think my text file has only one line?

Tags: macos, sed

I have a text file with about 300 lines of copy, separated by carriage returns. I tried to use sed (on Mac OSX) to find a match and output which line the match was found in, but it says it's on line 1. What's going on?

```
sed -n '/pattern/=' /path/to/file.txt
```

Sample of file.txt

```
text text text
text text text
text pattern text
text text text
```

Result:

```
1
```

What's going on here? Are my return characters wrong? Are there different kinds of returns?

Comment: Try `sed 's/\r/\n/g'` before running your `sed`.

Comment: What does `/$/=` output?

Comment: The dollar sign outputs "1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The file needs to have linefeeds, not carriage returns.